# Why isn't ipconfig /all working in WSL bash?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Cmder which is a terminal based on ConEmu, and Bash (not Git Bash) as my shell.
I've recently run into a couple of interesting issues where Bash shows that I have a different version of npm installed than cmd.exe or PowerShell shows. I managed to kind of sort of (although not fully) understand why that was happening. More frustratingly though, I can't seem to use ipconfig with any of the standard switches like /all on Bash (regular old ipconfig works). I have to open a new console dialog in Cmder and run cmd as my shell or just open cmd directly. Does anyone with experience using Bash on Windows understand why this happens and also how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: _ I can't seem to use ipconfig with any of the standard switches like /all_ What does "can't seem to use" mean? I don't see from your question, what commands you tried in bash and what response you got.  I am using Cygwin bash (not WSL), and `ipconfig` works fine.

Comment: BTW, may I suggest that you ask your question on [su] instead of [so], of course with adding the necessary details? I think it suits better there, because it sounds like a WSL / bash configuration issue.

Comment: @user1934428 I get the same output as if I had done ipconfig /? or ipconfig with an invalid flag like /asdfasdf, i.e., the help-message/usage-guide

Comment: And if you invoke it without any flags (i.e. just `ipconfig`), do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: @user1934428 No, that works as expected

Comment: Did you verify that you indeed invoke the **same** ipconfig from WSL as you would do from a Windows cmd shell?

Comment: @user1934428 To be honest, I'm not even sure how I would check.

Comment: Eh??? Simply with, i.e.,  `type -a ipconfig`....

Comment: @user1934428 Yeah that works in bash, but it doesn't work in cmd.exe or powershell so I don't know how to check if they're the same.

Comment: No, but once you know which ipconfig is used in bash, you can call explicitly the same in cmd shell (by specifying the full path) and see whether they behave the same. If the identical EXE would behave differently in this respect under bash and cmd, it would be weird.